# Cannot find the cause of Cycle Exception in simple model( MVC ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got a model where I have Business, Workers and Jobs, also there are WorrkerReports for a business in a specific Job for a Worker.

```
public class Business
{
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }

    public List<Job> jobs{ get; set; }
    public List<Worker> workers { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public int WorkerId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int BusinessId{ get; set; }
}

public class Inspector
{
    public int InspectorId { get; set; }
    public String Name{ get; set; }


}

public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string NameOfJob{ get; set; }
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
}

public class WorkerReport
{
    public int WorkerReportId { get; set; }
    public int InspectorId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }

    public Job job{ get; set; }
    public Worker worker{ get; set; }
    public Inspector Inspector { get; set; }
}
```

But when the model is generating i got this error:
**'FK_dbo.WorkerReports_dbo.Workers_WorkerId' on table 'WorkerReports' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.**

I don´t understand why i am getting this error,because  i don´t see where the cycle is being produced. Have anyone some idea? Where is the circle being caused?
Thanks a lot, provide help to a dessesperated programmer.

Comment: Are you using entity framework code first technique ?

Comment: Yes, MVC 4 ASP.NET and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two delete cascade path on `WorkerReport`.

- Business -> Worker -> WorkerReport
- Business -> Job -> WorkerReport

By default all the relationship are required and the convention enable all the delete cascade from `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`. The solution is to remove at least one of the cascade manually from `Worker` or `Job`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkerReport>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.job) // HasOptional for nullable FK
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

// modelBuilder.Entity<WorkerReport>()
//    .HasRequired(x => x.worker) // HasOptional for nullable FK
//    .WithMany()
//    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Or just disable all delete cascade by removing the default delete cascade convention.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Put it inside the the `DbContext` class.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // here
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I Put that ModelBuilder Code? In which class of the prohject?

Comment: ok, thanks by i am getting \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : La multiplicidad entra en conflicto con la restricción referencial en Role 'WorkerReport_Job_Target' de la relación 'WorkerReport_Job'. Dado que ninguna de las propiedades de Dependent Role acepta valores null, la multiplicidad de Principal Role debe ser '1'.

Comment: english:thanks i am getting by \ tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'WorkerReport_Job_Target' the 'WorkerReport_Job' relationship. Since none of the Dependent Role properties accepts null values​​, the multiplicity of Principal Role must be "1".

Comment: @xabier, use `HasRequired`, not `HasOptional` as my updated answer